# Translate city name in iOS just like reverseGeocodeLocation function does

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, geolocation

When I use `reverseGeocodeLocation` to fetch a coordinate with a placemark, I get the results in the language of the device. Do you know some function that I can call to translate this known locations? I tried `NSLocalizedString` and it doesn't do the job.

For example:
with reverseGeocodeLocation for certain coordinate I get **"Nueva York"** but if I try `NSLocalizedString("New York", nil)` I don't get **"Nueva York"**.

PS. The device language is spanish in this example.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: NSLocalizedString is not some magic translation function. Its looking in your app for a file that provides a translation string for a string  with the key "New York"

Comment: Look at the documentation.

Comment: Was going to say the same thing. You could however use the Google translate api to do what you need.

Comment: @Ohnomycoco The only caveat to that is I believe Google rate limits their api.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to force your language:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"zh-Hans"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

Note that replacing `zh-Hans` to your preferred language,such like:

> ko 한국어
>
> en English
>
> fr français
>
> de Deutsch
>
> ja 日本語
>
> nl Nederlands
>
> it Italiano
>
> es Español
>
> pt Português
>
> pt-PT Português (Portugal)
>
> da dansk
>
> fi suomi
>
> nb norsk bokmål
>
> sv svenska
>
> zh-Hans 中文（简体中文）
>
> zh-Hant 中文（繁體中文）
>
> ru русский
>
> pl polski
>
> tr Türkçe
>
> uk українська
>
> ar العربية
>
> hr hrvatski
>
> cs čeština
>
> el Ελληνικά
>
> he עברית
>
> ro română
>
> sk slovenčina
>
> th ไทย
>
> id Bahasa Indonesia
>
> en-GB English (United Kingdom)
>
> ca català
>
> hu magyar
>
> vi Tiếng Việt